# Get included file names PropertiesConfiguration configuration2

Tags: java, apache-config

I am looking for a way to get the names (path) of all the files added to a PropertiesConfiguration with the help of the include key "*include*".

**Example** 

*main.properties*

  key1 = value1

  key2 = value2

  key3 = value3

 include = additional.properties

*additional.properties*

additionalKey1 = additionalValue1

The aim is to add, remove, and especially **reload** said included files.

Comment: didn't get what you are asking

Comment: I want to add, remove, reload included property files.

Comment: I tried calling getString("include") on the configuration, but it returns null. Also looked through the API and found nothing straight forward so far. Sooo, here I am